# How to access all images from facebook album in Android

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am using facebook android sdk to access photos of each album,

```
response = facebook.request(wallAlbumID+"/photos");
```

But its response contains the object of 1st picture of the album. How can i get all the pictures of each album with respect to their id?

Comment: Could you clarify here. You say wallAlbumID/photos is what you're looking for - which should return the photos for the wallAlbumID. Then you ask about getting all pictures for each album. That is a little confusing. Also can you check what you get if you use the Graph API Explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: Same question arries to me please help any one